# How to print all inputs used from loop

Tags: java

I am trying to have an output where the entered numbers in the loop are all printed out as separate numbers. Example: *Entered numbers: 10, 15, 1, 25*.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumofNumbersAbove0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = 0;
        int input;
        for (input = 0; input >= 0;) {
            number = number + input;
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            input = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Entered Number: " + input);
        System.out.println("The sum: " + number);
    }
}
```

I get the sum of all the numbers correctly. But all I get for entered numbers is the final one.

Comment: You can't store multiple values in a single variable.  Each time you assign it, you overwrite the data that was stored previously.  If you want to store an arbitrary number of inputs, use an `int[]` or `List<Integer>` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Move your print of `input` into the loop where each value of `input` is actually present. Where you have it you only get the last `input`

```
for (input = 0; input >= 0;) {
    number = number + input;
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    System.out.println("Entered Number: " + input);
    input = scan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("The sum: " + number);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**
In your code the two variables you have `input` and `number` (which should rather be named sum) are solving very different purpose. `input` is acting a transient pedestrial where the user-entered values come and land. From there the value is added into `number` and then come another user-entered value which lands onto the same pedestrial thereby knocking-off the previous value.

Thus when you print `input` at the bottom of your code, the value you find is the one which came last to the pedestrial (which in your case is some integer < 0)

**Solution:** What you want is to perform an operation (print) on each of the input values. You can do either of the following-

1. *Perform the operation before losing the value*. I mean print the value in the loop itself. Adding the value to `number` is another operation you are already doing before losing the value
2. *Persist all the input values*. Here you need to have some *bigger* pedestrial which can accomodate all the incoming user-entered value without knocking-off previous values. Once you have all the them you can revisit the values and operate on them. printing them could be one operation and accumulating their values in another variable `number` could be another.

Hope that helps